# socket time out in socket programming

Tags: c#

i have a hardware than joins to a laptop(server)  in ad hoc Network.

when server sends data alone, it works correctly. and client sends data alone , works correctly too.

but when server and client send data together , after a period of time , time out will occur.

after 35 and sometimes 33 packet time out will occur.

i changed transfer rate of hardware but it disconnects too.

although hard ware supports full duplex.

after time out , i ping hard ware and it is not on port.

and check port on server , and it is open.

how can i do?

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[512];
        //try
        //{

            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("");
            // Gets first IP address associated with a localhost 
            IPAddress add = ipHost.AddressList[3];


            TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(add, 6000);
            tcpListener.Start();



            TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();


            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            String data = null;
            while (true)
            {
                int j = 0;
                int i;
                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    j = j + 1;
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    AddItem("j="+j+" Received:"+ data);

                    // Process the data sent by the client.
                    //data = data.ToUpper();

                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("thanks");

                    // Send back a response.
                    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                    AddItem("Sent:"+"thanks");


                }
                // Shutdown and end connection
                tcpClient.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard socket calls are all blocking, so if both participants are sending to each other, they each wait for their opposite to receive the message they send, causing a [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

In .NET, there are three typical solutions:

- Microsoft has a parallel API for [asynchronous socket activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It requires more overhead code than your example, but handles just about everything in a Windows-like manner.
- You can handle the asynchronous activity yourself by testing for readable data before you write with [`Socket.Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This is a typical polling approach, but you're doing everything yourself and need to make sure there's no starvation or other bias.
- Put your `Read` and `Write` code in different threads, so that blocking one doesn't block the entire program.

Comment: i changed my cod to below :

'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx'

but did not change.

Comment: how can i use different threads for read and write in my cod : while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {